# angular $resource query method not respecting query

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to return a specific item intead of the whole list like so :

```
exampleFactory.query({'_id': "SOME ID"}, function (item) {
         console.log(item);  //returns all items instead of just one
}
```

I also tried unsing .get but returns an error : TypeError: Object # has no method 'push'
    at copy

```
exampleFactory.get({'_id': "SOME ID"}, function (item) {
         console.log(item);
}
```

Here is the factory I am using:

```
app.factory('exampleFactory', ['$resource',
function($resource){
  return $resource(
    'api/items/:itemId',
    {
      itemId:'@_id'
    }
  )
}]);
```